# Appending to a list in a loop resets the list

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
deckTypes = []
cardType = ["Spade", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"]
cardValues = ["Ace", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"]
Values = [[1, 11], 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
for i in cardType:
    for j in cardValues:
        deckTypes.append(str(j) + " of " + str(i))
deck = dict(zip(deckTypes, Values*4))
z = 0
while z < 5:
    card = random.choice(list(deck))
    handValue = deck[card]
    hand = []
    hand.append(card)
    print(hand)
    z += 1
```

I''m trying to append to the list `hand` but it resets the list everytime the loop ends. So I get this:

```
['1 of Spade']
['3 of Spade']
['2 of Clubs']
['K of Hearts']
['4 of Spade']
```

How can I make it like this?

```
['1 of Spade', '3 of Spade', '2 of Clubs', 'K of Hearts', '4 of Spade']
```

PS: This is not all the entire code but I tried to make it as clear as possible to understand

Comment: Move `hand = []` to outside of the `while`.

Comment: wow how did i not see that

Comment: You are initialising the list to []  then add one card - there will be at most one card in it like this. Vting to close as typo - this kind of Q pops up weekly :) can't find a dupe though

Comment: You might want to give [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a read if you do not know it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code output is in this

```
['3 of Hearts']
['9 of Spade']
['3 of Spade']
['Ace of Diamonds']
['Q of Clubs']
```

But when you move hand = [] and print (hand) out of while loop as this

```
deckTypes = []
cardType = ["Spade", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"]
cardValues = ["Ace", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"]
Values = [[1, 11], 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
for i in cardType:
    for j in cardValues:
        deckTypes.append(str(j) + " of " + str(i))
deck = dict(zip(deckTypes, Values*4))
z = 0
hand = []
while z < 5:
    card = random.choice(list(deck))
    handValue = deck[card]
    hand.append(card)
    z += 1
print(hand)
```

Output will be:

```
['7 of Spade', '4 of Clubs', '10 of Clubs', '4 of Spade', '4 of Hearts']
```

Comment: Please don't include output as images. Include text as text.

Answer (score 1):

**You have misplaced the initialization of `hand`.**

---

With your current code, `hand` is set to `[]` *during each iteration*:

```
z = 0
while z < 5:
    hand = [] # Executed during each iteration
    hand.append(card)
    print(hand)
    z += 1
```

So after each iteration you get a list with only 1 element:

```
['1 of Spade']
['3 of Spade']
['2 of Clubs']
['K of Hearts']
['4 of Spade']
```

---

Instead, you should initialize `hand` *before looping*, like this:

```
hand = [] # Executed once, before iterating
z = 0
while z < 5:
    hand.append(card)
    print(hand)
    z += 1
```

Now, you can see that the elements are being correctly appended to your list at each iteration:

```
['1 of Spade']
['1 of Spade', '3 of Spade']
['1 of Spade', '3 of Spade', '2 of Clubs']
['1 of Spade', '3 of Spade', '2 of Clubs', 'K of Hearts']
['1 of Spade', '3 of Spade', '2 of Clubs', 'K of Hearts', '4 of Spade']
```

When you exit the loop, `hand` contains the following list, as you wanted:

```
['1 of Spade', '3 of Spade', '2 of Clubs', 'K of Hearts', '4 of Spade']
```